# Getting list of available Wifi's on react native(android)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I want to get the available WiFi networks on my react-native android app. I went through a few blog posts and StackOverflow questions, but I am unable to achieve the desired functionality.
react-native-android-wifi is an npm package, which is expected to achieve the functionality, but I am getting an error of `PermissionsAndroid` not defined when trying to execute the code for asking user's permission to enable WiFi. Below is the code,

```
    try {
          const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
            PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            {
              'title': 'Wifi networks',
              'message': 'We need your permission in order to find wifi networks'
            }
          )
          if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
            console.log("Thank you for your permission! :)");
          } else {
            console.log("You will not able to retrieve wifi available networks list");
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.warn(err)
        }
```

Can someone please help me out here and please tell me how can I reach my desired outcome.

Comment: Did you import `PermissionsAndroid`. Check out the official [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid)

Answer (score 0):

I used this in one of my projects https://github.com/blackdeve/react-native-wifi

Actually the library doesn't have a documented method for listing out available wifis but looking at the source code you can see there is a public method called  **loadWifiList**

You need to follow the instructions on the github page and add stuff to settings.gradle. Here is the method I am talking about:

```
@ReactMethod
public void loadWifiList(Callback successCallback, Callback errorCallback) {

}
```